# How To Configure Twitter External Authentication in ASP.NET Core 3.0 Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, twitter

I've added the Twitter external sign-in NuGet package to my ASP.NET Core 3 app as outlined on the following Microsoft page.

[Twitter external sign-in setup with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/twitter-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

This is a screenshot of a portion of the doc:
[Configure Twitter Authentication DefaultScheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMTlG.png)

Now I'm trying to access and modify the /signin-twitter default callback that was set up automatically by the NuGet installation. Also, I want to setup my own DefaultScheme to process authentications.

I have 2 questions.

1. How do I access and modify the code in the /signin-twitter default callback that is set up automatically by the Twitter authentication NuGet package? There is no /signin-twitter file or component in the application file structure. And a search does not find "signin-twitter" text mentioned in any file. Where is the /signin-twitter code located?
2. In the attached screenshot, you'll see the verbiage that says "The AddAuthentication(String) overload sets the DefaultScheme property". But the doc has no example that shows how to do this. How do I set up my own DefaultScheme to process authentications using AddAuthentication(String)? And what type of code file should it be?

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Callback URL can be customized by adding callback options when setting up twitter authentication:

   ```
   services.AddAuthentication().AddTwitter(twitterOptions =>
   {
       ...
       twitterOptions.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-twitter2");
   });
   ```

   Default callback path "/signin-twitter" is defined from [TwitterOptions.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/Twitter/src/TwitterOptions.cs), which can be overridden above. The [RemoteAuthenticationHandler.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/RemoteAuthenticationHandler.cs) will check if a request matches this callback path and take action.

   To implement additional business logic upon [successful Twitter login](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/Twitter/src/TwitterHandler.cs#L134), define [OnCreatingTicket event](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/Twitter/src/TwitterEvents.cs):

   ```
   services.AddAuthentication().AddTwitter(twitterOptions =>
   {
       ...
       twitterOptions.Events = new TwitterEvents()
       {
           OnCreatingTicket = context =>
           {
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"TwitterEvents.OnCreatingTicket: UserId = {context.UserId}");
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"TwitterEvents.OnCreatingTicket: AccessToken = {context.AccessToken}");
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"TwitterEvents.OnCreatingTicket: AccessTokenSecret = {context.AccessTokenSecret}");
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"TwitterEvents.OnCreatingTicket: User = {context.User}");
               return Task.CompletedTask;
           }
       };
       ...
       // Commented because probably you are not asking for this
       //twitterOptions.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-twitter2");
   });
   ```
2. Authentication Scheme can be customized like this:

   ```
   services.AddAuthentication(options => {
       ...
       options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "abc";
   })
   .AddTwitter("abc", options => {
       ...
   })
   ```

   You may refer to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme) for further illustration.

Comment: Hi Bill Lam. I actually did try what you suggested. However, I couldn't figure out how to access/recreate the /signin-twitter code portions that interact with the database. I need to add that database interaction code to my /signin-twitter2. Your response to my question is very much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for missing first part of the question. You may implement your business logic by defining the OnCreatingTicket TwitterEvents. This event will be fired upon successful login.

Comment: Bill, this is largely what I was looking for. I especially wanted to access the Twitter user data. Thank you. I'll be diving into it starting today. And thanks again to @Shoejep. I'll be testing his suggestions as well. Stay safe and healthy!

Comment: Does it work for you? Kindly mark any workable solutions as answer to help others to solve similar problems too. Thanks!

Comment: Yes Bill, your suggestions put me on the right track. The part of your response that helped the most was directing me to the OnCreatingTicket event handler. That gave me access to the Twitter user data that I needed. Thank u again.  Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about schemes and the like but if you want to customise the Twitter callback, you need to make your own `TwitterOptions` and `TwitterHandler`.

If you look at the source code for `AddTwitter`, found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/3ea1fc7aac9d43152908d5d45ae811f3df7ca399/src/Security/Authentication/Twitter/src/TwitterExtensions.cs), you can see it uses the `TwitterOptions` and `TwitterHandler` classes, these are basically configs to tell OAuth how to behave.

```
return builder.AddRemoteScheme<TwitterOptions, TwitterHandler>(authenticationScheme, displayName, configureOptions);
```

If you so wish, it looks like you can pass an authentication scheme as well.

[Twitter Options](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/62351067ff4c1401556725b401478e648b66acdc/src/Security/Authentication/Twitter/src/TwitterOptions.cs)

[Twitter Handler](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b6b5319bab88e4e665e2c4d750017f5c6ef93a37/src/Security/Authentication/Twitter/src/TwitterHandler.cs)

If you want to customise the callback, you'll need to change `HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync`.

I haven't tried it but you could probably do something like this below.

**MyTwitterHandler.cs**

```
public class MyTwitterHandler: TwitterHandler  {

    protected override async Task<HandleRequestResult> HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var result = await base.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync();
        
        //write custom code here

        return result;
    }

}
```

**Extensions.cs**

```
public static AuthenticationBuilder AddMyTwitter(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<TwitterOptions> configureOptions)
{
      builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IPostConfigureOptions<TwitterOptions>, TwitterPostConfigureOptions>());
      return builder.AddRemoteScheme<TwitterOptions, MyTwitterHandler>("MyAuthenticationScheme", TwitterDefaults.DisplayName, configureOptions);
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
.AddMyTwitter(options => {

 });`
```

Comment: This looks like the path I should follow @Shoejep. I'll try it later today and follow-up with you. Your time and response are greatly appreciated.